# I bought a domain namespace at AWS, can I setup an email addresses using this domain at AWS?

Tags: email, web-services, amazon, email-address

I bought a domain namespace at AWS and I'd like to know is it possible to setup an email address using this domain at AWS?

For example, let's say I bought `boughtwebspace.example`at AWS.

Is it possible to create an email address using this domain name i.e.
`Jeff@boughtwebspace.example` using AWS?

Answer (score 2):

AWS recently launched a product for this called [Amazon WorkMail](https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/).  Their [pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/pricing/) says:

> With Amazon WorkMail, there are no upfront fees, no required minimum commitments, and no long-term contracts.
>
> Amazon WorkMail costs $4 per user per month and includes 50 GB of mailbox storage for each user. You can get started with a 30-day free trial for up to 25 users.

$4 per month is competitive email hosting pricing.  It isn't the cheapest, but it is cheaper than some of the big players in the space such as hosted Gmail (Google G Suite.)

Keep in mind that you are free to choose any hosted email service that you want.  Even if you control the domain entirely through AWS, you can set the MX records for mail to point wherever you want.   If you are looking to compare providers search Google for things like "hosted email reviews" or "email mailboxes reviews."

Answer (score 0):

> using AWS?

[Amazon Simple Email Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) is an AWS-based email service.

Edit: As [Stephen](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/14543/stephen-ostermiller) mentioned in the comments, this is used primarily for automation. His answer (Amazon WorkMail) is more likely what you’re looking for.

Comment: Isn't that for receiving email only? Thanks

Comment: Amazon SES can be used to both [send](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-email.html) and [receive](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email.html) email.

Comment: SES is geared towards email automation.   Their email receiving looks like it is meant for use cases like customer support automation.     It looks like you might be able to create rules to forward the email using it.